# The Command or Action 'SaveRecord' isn't available now

Tags: vba, ms-access

When using this code:

```
If Me.BU_DAT_ZAHL < Date Then
    Me.BU_DAT_ZAHL = Date
    Call MsgBox("Zahlungsdatum wurde auf heute gestellt!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Formalprüfung Anweisung")
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
```

In the line: "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord" ms-access throws the following error (nr. 2046)

```
The Command or Action 'SaveRecord' isn't available now
```

Has anybody an idea why this error is thrown? Is there a way to find out what the problem is?

We already tried:

- setting the focus with me.setFocus => no change
- Updating via sql RunSql => write conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the *Dirty* property:

```vb
If Me.BU_DAT_ZAHL < Date Then
    Me.BU_DAT_ZAHL = Date
    Me.Dirty = False
    Call MsgBox("Zahlungsdatum wurde auf heute gestellt!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Formalprüfung Anweisung")
End If
```

If that fails too, something is blocking the save action.

As a side note - be careful not scaring the user. This happening is in no way critical, your code has taken care of the situation, and all you wish is to let the user know that:

```
Call MsgBox("Zahlungsdatum wurde auf heute gestellt.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Formalprüfung Anweisung")
```

Comment: This worked for me (we changed the msgbox too :-) But I still dont know what exactly the problem was. What is the difference between "SaveRecord" and "me.dirty"?

Comment: DoCmd.Etc calls a menu commands which can be dependent on the cursor position.